# 1999 Ford Ranger Exhaust Repair

Tags: ford, exhaust, ranger

I have a 1999 Ford Ranger with a 3L 6v flex fuel 2 door extended cab with a 6 ft bed. I need to replace the entire exhaust, however I cannot find a Y-pipe for the catalytic converter. All the parts are stock, and not a single parts site has a Y-pipe for it. Where can I find this part, or is it the wrong name for this part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is actually the catalytic converters. If you take a look at the **DAVICO MANUFACTURING Part # 59261** you'll see the cats are incorporated into the Y-pipe and gets you what you need. They call it an *Exact-Fit Catalytic Converter*. I'm sure there are other brands out there as well.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Those 2 small things your calling catalytic converters are actually resonators the cat is after the connection just before the downstream O2 sensor. Why would there ever be 3 cat's on any vehicle?

Comment: If in your answer you're referring to the image in my answer, I'm afraid to say you're wrong. The image is of the cats, which are incorporated into the Y-Pipe.  You can look up the part number and tell I'm spot on.